# Subset data based on another data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two data sets `dat1` and `dat2`, that look like:

```
a<-c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(1,2), rep(2,4), rep(1,2))
b<-c(rep("AA", 8), rep("BB", 6), rep("CC", 2))
v<-c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", 
"x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x5", "x8")
ab<-c(1,2,5,6,58,2,4,14,2,25,23,1,12,14,15,14)
dat1<-data.frame(a,b,v,ab)
names(dat1)<-c("loc", "point", "sp", "ab")

a<-c(rep(1,8), rep(2,4), rep(3, 2), rep(1,4))
b<-c(rep("AA", 8), rep("BB", 6), rep("DD", 4))
v<-c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y6", "y7", "y8", "y12",
"y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5", "y6", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y6")
ab<-c(1,2,45,14,1,12,14,15,10,2,32,14,1,12,18,9,6,7)
dat2<-data.frame(a,b,v,ab)
names(dat2)<-c("loc", "point", "sp", "ab")
```

and I need to make subsets of these dataframes, where each subset contains only combinations of `loc` and `point` which are in `dat1` and `dat2`.
My result should look like:

```
res1
   loc point sp ab
1    1    AA x1  1
2    1    AA x2  2
3    1    AA x3  5
4    1    AA x4  6
5    1    AA x5 58
11   2    BB x6 23
12   2    BB x7  1
13   2    BB x8 12
14   2    BB x9 14

res2
   loc point  sp ab
1    1    AA  y1  1
2    1    AA  y2  2
3    1    AA  y3 45
4    1    AA  y4 14
5    1    AA  y6  1
6    1    AA  y7 12
7    1    AA  y8 14
8    1    AA y12 15
9    2    BB  y1 10
10   2    BB  y2  2
11   2    BB  y3 32
12   2    BB  y4 14
```

I have tried `merge()` and than divide the result in two dataframes, but there are not same number of rows, so the rows of smaller data multiplied to fill the gaps. My tries with `subset()` also failed.

This is simialar to [Subset a data frame based on another](http://df1=data.frame(id=c(1552,%201552,%202501,%202504,%202504,%202504),%20month=c(4,%206,%207,%203,%204,%204),%20year=c(1970,%201970,%201971,%201971,%201971,%201972),%20weight=c(135,%20654,%20164,%2083,%20155,%20195),%20sex=c('F',%20'F',%20'M',%20'F',%20'F',%20'F'))%20%20df2=%20data.frame%20(id=c(1552,%202504),%20month=c(6,%204),%20year=c(1970,%201971))) but I havent succeed even when I triend their solutions (ie. `intersect`).

Thx for help!

Comment: You are right, i have yet editted my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you can try:

```
merge(dat1, unique(dat2[,1:2]))
merge(dat2, unique(dat1[,1:2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`semi_join` in the **dplyr** package is designed for this:

```
library(dplyr)
# get just the rows in dat1 that have matches in dat2
dat1 %>% semi_join(dat2, by=c('loc', 'point'))
```